# Ruby Excon SSL SocketError: read finished A

Tags: ruby, ssl, amazon-s3, fog, excon

Using Ruby on Rails with Carrierwave + Fog, which relies on Excon to connect to S3. The Rails server is being run on AWS EC2. Most of the time, the Carrierwave uploader works fine, but often I get the following error and stack trace:

```
Excon::Errors::SocketError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
…y/gems/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb: 105:in `connect_nonblock'
…y/gems/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb: 105:in `block in initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:  91:in `block in timeout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:  35:in `block in catch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:  35:in `catch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:  35:in `catch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb: 106:in `timeout'
…y/gems/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb: 101:in `initialize'
…y/gems/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/connection.rb: 414:in `new'
…y/gems/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/connection.rb: 414:in `socket'
…y/gems/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/connection.rb: 126:in `request_call'
…/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/middlewares/mock.rb:  42:in `request_call'
…ems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/middlewares/instrumentor.rb:  22:in `request_call'
…/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:  15:in `request_call'
…/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:  15:in `request_call'
…/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:  15:in `request_call'
…y/gems/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/connection.rb: 269:in `request'
…/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:  12:in `error_call'
…/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:  10:in `error_call'
…/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:  10:in `error_call'
…y/gems/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/connection.rb: 292:in `rescue in request'
…y/gems/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/connection.rb: 229:in `request'
…/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:  12:in `error_call'
…/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:  10:in `error_call'
…/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:  10:in `error_call'
…y/gems/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/connection.rb: 292:in `rescue in request'
…y/gems/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/connection.rb: 229:in `request'
…/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:  12:in `error_call'
…/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:  10:in `error_call'
…/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:  10:in `error_call'
…y/gems/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/connection.rb: 292:in `rescue in request'
…y/gems/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.36.0/lib/excon/connection.rb: 229:in `request'
…/2.1.0/gems/fog-core-1.22.0/lib/fog/core/connection.rb:  56:in `request'
…cal/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fog-1.22.1/lib/fog/xml.rb:  23:in `request'
…ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fog-1.22.1/lib/fog/aws/storage.rb: 535:in `request'
…/fog-1.22.1/lib/fog/aws/requests/storage/put_object.rb:  31:in `put_object'
…1.0/gems/fog-1.22.1/lib/fog/aws/models/storage/file.rb: 199:in `save'
…/2.1.0/gems/fog-core-1.22.0/lib/fog/core/collection.rb:  51:in `create'
…gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb: 261:in `store'
…gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:  80:in `store!'
…s/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:  59:in `block in store!'
…rrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:  17:in `with_callbacks'
…s/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:  58:in `store!'
…2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb: 375:in `store!'
…2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb: 207:in `store_finish_image!'
```

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

As a first step I would recommend upgrading to 0.37.0. There is a bug around chunked encoding that I fixed there, not sure it would manifest in this way, but best to reduce the possibilities before going too far down a wrong path.

UPDATE: Nothing jumps out at me, but writing should be idempotent. If this is intermittent, it might be best/easiest to just rescue/retry for this particular error.

Comment: I've upgraded all my gems, including excon to 0.37.0, and I'm still seeing the same error come up.